# SqlConnection was unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

In the below code I have a dropdown now i like to bind all values from database to my dropdownlist.But I got this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Please help me to rectify this issue.

```
void getdata()
{
    string strConnection = "Data Source=GMAS-PC3;Initial Catalog=FormMaster8;User Id=sa;Password=sa123;";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    string com = "Select BatchName from BatchTable";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adpt.Fill(dt);//error occur
    cbProject.DataSource = dt;
    cbProject.DataBind();
    cbProject.DataTextField = "BatchName";
    cbProject.DataValueField = "BatchTable";
    cbProject.DataBind();
 }
```

Asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbProject" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

Comment: Make sure your SQL Server service is running.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have opened up your firewall to allow external connections to your database server. See [this Microsoft link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx) on how to do this for your operating system.

The default port for a sql server database instance is 1433, so you'll have to make sure that is open for incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

try UDL to generate the correct connection string and test it
http://jcluthedevelopment.com/tutorials/udl-trick-for-getting-a-connection-string/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar where an error occurs somewhere in the code and you don't put the connection inside a Try...Catch...Finally block, and close the connection in the Finally block.

The error causes zombie connections on the SQL Server that don't expire. Check your SQL Server activity monitor for a lot more connections than you expect in your app.

You also don't have a call to the Open() method on your connection.